# Regex to return the characters between square brackets (but not the brackets)

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a RegEx to return all the characters between two square brackets, and only the characters, not the brackets themselves.

For example given a string that looks like `"[A][B2][1,1][ABC]"`

The RegEx should return: `A`, `B2`, `1,1`, `ABC`

I have tried various expressions for both `String#split` and `Pattern` & `Match`.

The closest I've gotten was:

`String.split("[\\[]*[\\]]");`
and
`Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]+(?=])");`

Both of these return: `[A`, `[B2`, `[1,1`, `[ABC`

I've found other expressions that return the values with the enclosing brackets (ie. `Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*\\]");`) but that is not what I'm after.

Does someone know the correct expression? or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])
```

You need `lookaheads` and `lookbehinds`.or

```
(?<=\\[)[^\\]]*(?=\\])
```

Comment: You do not need lookarounds.

Comment: That was quick! I've tested both with `Pattern` and both worked perfectly with my test data.

Comment: I would, but there is a timer :p

Comment: lol, I'm not one of those ... I *tick* those that provide a correct answer :) I also _dislike_ those that never tick answers!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a [**capturing group**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to retain the part of the pattern you want.

```
String s  = "[A][B2][1,1][ABC]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^]]*)]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/7Wletj)

Comment: Have you really tried that code? I just ran it and the returned output was _with_ brackets!

Comment: Sorry, you're right :) but vks was a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

Comment: Nope, I've already tried that one. It is one of those that returns the values including the brackets, which is not what I'm after,

Comment: You need to get group(1) not group(0).